# Решение задачи JS

Tags: javascript, функции

Целый день искал ответ на одну задачку по js, но так и ничего не нашел. Возможно поможет сообщество.

Есть данный код:

```js
var a = 1;
if (a) {
  function test() {};
  a += /* ? */ test;
}
console.log(a);
```

Вопрос: Что нужно подставить вместо **?**, чтобы выход был - "1function", если записать код без **?** то выход - "1function test() {}". Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 2):

Оператор `typeof` возвращает тип операнда, в виде строки. Для функций, это `"function"`

```js
var a = 1;
if (a) {
  function test() {};
  a += typeof test;
}
console.log(a);
```

P.s. Сейчас функции можно объявлять где угодно. Где-то в будущем ( [use strict](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) ) объявление функций внутри блоков if или циклов, может считаться ошибкой. Поэтому стоит избегать такого кода, и объявлять функции вне if.

Comment: Какой же я тупой. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @Rainman Это задача скорее на знание, чем на соображалку...

Comment: Когда начал изучать js то читал о typeof, но счел не нужным особого внимания. Сейчяс взялся за решение задач и забыл о нем. Видимо рановато мне еще задчки решать

Comment: Задачки решать никогда не рановато. Это хоть какая-то практика кодирования, без неё теория не будет закрепляться. Теперь вот вы лучше поймёте и запомните `typeof`)

Comment: Если быть точным, вместо `?` нужно вставить не `typeof` а `*/ typeof /*`, иначе typeof останется в комментарии :D